# how to include a Check in the Lwuit command?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

Hi I want to include a check (as in a tick mark) besides the command on the display screen.IS there any way I can implement it?

Comment: @bhakki- the way we implement the commands..exit,ok etc.. I want a way to display which command is being displayed..something like setfocus.. but the selected part should be tick marked

Comment: Where do u want to achieve this?  menubar or softbutton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the new class with implement the ListCellRenderer interface or extend with DefaultListCellRenderer class. Then implement all abstract methods and override getListCellRendererComponent method like this,

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, 
                                             int index, boolean isSelected) {

        if (isSelected && list.hasFocus()) {
// do selected style that means selected command style
        } else {
// do unselected style that means unselected command style    
        }
return this;
    }
```

For your reference see this [link](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html).

Finally you need to pass this renderer class to setMenuRenderer method.

For single form means do like this,

```
Form form = new Form();
form.setMenuRenderer(new MenuRenderer()); // pass your created render class
```

For all form means do like this,

```
UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel()
          .setMenuRenderer(new MenuRenderer()); // pass your created render class
```